# Error al modificar el usuario (contraseñas) desde la pagina web. Django python

Tags: python, django, web, cuenta-usuario

estoy haciendo un proyecto final para el curso de Python. Lo que hago es ingresar a la pagina con un usuario común y editarlo. Solamente tengo para editar Correo, Contraseña (password1, password2). Al entrar al db_auth el correo cambia pero las contraseñas no. No se en que estoy equivocandome. No me salta error pero no cambia la contraseña.

Esto es el views.py

```html
@login_required
def editar_usuario(request):

    if request.method == "GET":
        form = UserEditForm(initial={"email": request.user.email})
        return render(request, "registration/editar_usuario.html", {"form": form})
    else:
        form = UserEditForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            data = form.cleaned_data

            usuario = request.user

            usuario.email = data["email"]
            usuario.password1 = data["password1"]
            usuario.password2 = data["password2"]
            usuario.save()
            messages.success(request, "Has modificado correctamente, ingresa tu usuario actualizado.")
            return redirect(to="login")
        else:
            return render(request, "registration/editar_usuario.html", {"form": form})
```

Esto es el forms.py

```html
class UserEditForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(label="Correo nuevo")
    password1 = forms.CharField(label="Contraseña nueva", widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label="Confirmar contraseña nueva", widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ["email", "password1", "password2"]
        help_texts = {"email": "", "password1": "", "password2": "" }
```

Esto es el urls.py

```html
from django.urls import path, include
from .views import *

urlpatterns = [
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),   
    path('registro/', registro, name="registro"),
    path('editar-usuario/', editar_usuario, name="editar_usuario"),
]
```

y este es el editar_usuario.html

```html
{% extends 'productos/base.html' %}


{% block contenido %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}


    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6 offset-md-3">
                <br><br>
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">


                        <h2 style="text-align:center;">Editar usuario</h2>
                        <hr>
                        <form method="post">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            {{form | crispy}}
                            <a href="{% url 'home' %}">Ir al inicio</a> |
                            <input type="submit" value="Editar" class="btn btn-success float-right">

                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br><br>

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>



{% endblock contenido %}
```

Por cierto el html de la pagina base esta puesta en otra app aqui el codigo

```html
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            <div class="container px-4 px-lg-5">
                <a class="navbar-brand">Cerveceria Romz</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0 ms-lg-4">
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="{% url 'home' %}">Productos</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'nosotros' %}">Nosotros</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'contacto' %}">Contacto</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Clientes</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">                                                                                            
                            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'editar_usuario' %}"> Editar usuario: @{{user.username}}</a></li>
                                <li><hr class="dropdown-divider" /></li>
                                {% if perms.productos.add_producto %}
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'agregar_producto' %}">Agregar productos</a></li>  
                                {% endif %}
                                {% if perms.productos.view_producto %}                                
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'listar_productos' %}">Modificar/Eliminar productos</a></li>     
                                {% endif %}

                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Cerrar sesion</a></li>

                            {% else %}
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'login' %}">Iniciar sesion</a></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'registro' %}">Registrate</a></li>

                            {% endif %}                                                                    
                                
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que usas password1 y password2 para verificar que la contraseña este correcta, para poder guardar una contraseña desde un form lleva un procedimiento especial ya que es necesario hashearla, lo que tu haces es esto:

```
usuario = request.user
usuario.email = data["email"]
usuario.password1 = data["password1"]
usuario.password2 = data["password2"]
usuario.save()
```

La manera correcta para guardar el password1 seria:

```
usuario = request.user
usuario.email = data["email"]
usuario.set_password(data["password1"]
usuario.save()
```

Puedes leer un poco mas de set_password aquí: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.set_password

Espero esto te sea de ayuda, si es así puedes marcar la respuesta como aceptada.